# Pass PHP array to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in PHP like this:

```
$link_array = [
  "Our_dogs" => "ourdogs.php",
  "About_us" => "aboutus.php",
  "Puppies" => "puppies.php",
  "Contact" => "contact.php",
  "Login" => "login.php",
  "Guestbook" => "guestbook.php"
];
```

I want to pass this array to javascript and then print it on my page, but if Im on, for example, the page for Our dogs, I dont want that link to show. Is that possible?

I have tried this:

```
foreach($link_array as $key=>$value){
    if(($key == "Our_dogs") && ($value == "ourdogs.php")){
        $_SESSION['Our dogs'] = $value;
      break;
 }

 $responseText['Our_dogs'] = $_SESSION['Our_dogs'];
 echo json_encode($responseText);
```

And this for JS:

```
var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var li = document.createElement('li');
        console.log(response.Our_dogs);
        li.innerHTML = '<a href=\"' + response.Our_dogs + '\">OUR DOGS</a>';
        byId("nav").appendChild(li);
```

but Im new to this and not sure how to do this. How can I do this in a correct way and is it possible to print only the links to the other pages (not the page showing)?

Comment: I assume you're retrieving the list through an AJAX call?  If so, what is your call currently returning?  Also, are you currently receiving any errors, etc.?

Comment: You can refer this link: http://thisinterestsme.com/passing-php-array-javascript/

Comment: Yes, Im retrieving the list through an AJAX call. No errors, just that i dont know how to pass all the links through correctly and show just the ones I want to show. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even need JavaScript?

You can do it like this:

```
$link_array = [
   "Our_dogs" => "ourdogs.php",
   "About_us" => "aboutus.php",
   "Puppies" => "puppies.php",
   "Contact" => "contact.php",
   "Login" => "login.php",
   "Guestbook" => "guestbook.php"
];

foreach($link_array as $key=>$value){
   // note that $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns filename with prepended slash
   if( '/' . $value != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ){
      echo '<li><a href="' . $value . '">' . $key . '</a></li>';
   }
}
```

You need to add foreach loop in ul#nav tag.

This code is not tested and I'm assuming that your not calling ajax request.

**UPDATE:**

```
$link_array = [
   "Our_dogs" => "ourdogs.php",
   "About_us" => "aboutus.php",
   "Puppies" => "puppies.php",
   "Contact" => "contact.php",
   "Login" => "login.php",
   "Guestbook" => "guestbook.php"
];

echo json_encode($link_array);
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   ...
})
.done(function( response ) {
   var currentUrl = window.location.href 
   var currentUrlLastPart = currentUrl.substr(s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   for (var key in response)
      if(val != currentUrlLastPart){
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerHTML = '<a href="' + response[key] + '">' + key + '</a>';
          document.getElementById("nav").appendChild(li);
      }
   });
});
```

Something like this?

Comment: I need to pass it to javascript because I want to pass them into an if-statement i have and only show some of the links to logged in users.

Comment: Thanks, that might work, but is that really javascript or is it jQuery maybe?

Comment: @Isla Ajax call is jQuery, everything else is pure Javascript. I was guessing that you already have your Ajax call.